# Connect AWS lambda to external Kafka service which is exposed via kafka proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda

I am new to Kafka, I am looking for a solution where I can publish the data from AWS lambda to the third party managed Kafka service which is exposed to the internet only via Kafka proxy.
What are the ways through which I can achieve that?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're running into? Isnt this just a regular HTTP call? If you're communicating with a proxy, then Kafka doesn't really matter

Comment: @OneCricketeer To be more specific when you say HTTP call then you mean to use HTTP REST API?

Comment: If you're using the Kafka REST Proxy from Confluent that exposes an HTTP REST API, then yes

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.